# Formatting a table, 2 arrays using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem when trying to format a table created with two arrays using ng-repeat. I have the two arrays; game.Teams[0].Scores and game.Teams[1].Scores, and the following html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Team 0 Scores
        </th>
        <th>
            Team 1 Scores
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="score in game.Teams[0].Scores">
        <td>
            {{score.ExtraPoints}}
        </td>
        <td>
            ????
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to loop over both lists and fill the second column with items from the second list. Is this achievable with ng-repeat, or will I have to merge the two and loop over a combined list?

Comment: Could you setup a different array with the two teams scores when you retreive it from the server?  (Or change what the server is sending)?  So you'd have an array like game.Scores[0].team[0], game.Scores[0].team[1], and game.Scores[1].team[0], game.Scores[1].team[1], ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both teams have the same amount of items

```
<table ng-init="scores = game.Teams[0].Scores.length > game.Teams[1].Scores.length ? game.Teams[0].Scores : game.Teams[1].Scores">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Team 0 Scores
        </th>
        <th>
            Team 1 Scores
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="score in scores">
        <td>
            {{game.Teams[0].Scores[$index].ExtraPoints}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{game.Teams[1].Scores[$index].ExtraPoints}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: you can do that `ngInit` part in the controller, just showing how it can be done all in the view.

Comment: They will have a different amount of items, so I would need another counter than the $index I guess

Comment: So at one point, Team 0 Scores could be longer than Team 1.  The table will have empty cells (`<td>`s) for Team 1

Comment: Yes, but the other way would be problematic; if Team 1 is longer than Team 0. Then it wouldn't fill the column.