# How to make 2 Angular Lists appear next to each other in a html table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, list, html-table

I am having a problem where when I run this code which reads data from 2 files both containing 10 numbers. These are both stored seperately in the mainlist but the only problem is when I try to output them into a table, instead of putting each one under its title it just puts both under the "List1" title in a 20 long list. So how do I make `mainlist[0]` appear under list 1 and `mainlist[1]` under list 2. Sorry that my code is very messy and very basic as I have only just started learning JS and Angular.

```html
 <div id="Tables">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>List1</th>
    <th>List2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in mainlist[0]">
     <td>{{i}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in mainlist[1]">
     <td>{{i}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tr>

  </table>
     </div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xz8pf7uk/)

Comment: Here is a solution for your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591693/formatting-a-table-2-arrays-using-ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're liking Javascript and AngularJS so far! To answer your question the way that tables are created via HTML is row based and not column based meaning `<tr>` encapsulates cells,`<td>`, so to create tables you are filling in rows by cells. To accomplish what you want solely through HTML and no additional Javascript you could think of your data being **two** cells within a **single** row instead of several rows per column.

I wrote up a quick example of how you could accomplish this through nesting tables. So why nest tables and not just put `<td><tr></tr></td>`? Row elements cannot be placed within cell elements, but tables can! If you try to place `<tr>` within `<td>` it will be rendered ignoring `<td>`.

I hope this answers your question.

https://jsfiddle.net/krd4p0yt/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.mainList = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6]
    ];
  }
]);
```

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <table>
      <th>List 1</th>
      <th>List 2</th>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in mainList[0]">
              <td>{{i}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in mainList[1]">
              <td>{{i}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your case based on the fact that the two lists have equal length:

```
<table ng-init="items = mainList[0]">
    <tr>
        <th>
            List 1
        </th>
        <th>
            List 2
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>
            {{item}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{mainList[1][$index]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```